# Making change in tpl file doesn't effect on Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.6

I am totally new in Prestashop. I am trying to modify blockcart.tpl which is located in ../theme/module/ folder. But whatever I change it doesn't make no effect in the frontend. Even if I delete the entire code from the bolckcart.tpl, I noticed there is no change in the source code of module block cart section.

I want to add plus-minus quantity button in the block cart. I am actually not sure whether I am editing the correct file or not.

Comment: Remove cache by admin panel in advenced settings/performance or by ftp (cache/smarty/cache and compile).

Comment: Post any questions on stackoverflow, not by email.